# Perhaps add English tag synonym?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

I was looking at [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21245/2604) and wanted to add the series tag for it. Unfortunately, there's no tag to the effect of [the-irregular-at-magic-high-school](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-irregular-at-magic-high-school). Since the title sounded reasonably familiar, I thought I'd search for `irregular magic` in the site to check if some form of the Japanese title was being used instead, and it turns out [mahouka-koukou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahouka-koukou) is being used right now.

Might some tag with some form of the English title be added as a synonym? At least as someone who doesn't follow the series, this was a bit confusing, and fact that the post initially was only tagged with [music](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) doesn't seem to be a point in favour of the current state of things.

Of course, it's possible that this is a series where the Japanese title is either easy to remember (e.g. *Gin no Saji*) or used frequently enough on the internet (e.g. SnK) that this wouldn't matter to the asker: I wouldn't know since I don't follow the series.

Comment: So you entered the variant of the work's title that you knew and  found the tag you were looking for. Is there really need to have a synonym now?

Comment: @Hakase: I didn't know the Japanese title and was almost going to put [tag:retag] on the question and ask a question about it on meta. The only reason I didn't was because I vaguely recalled questions on the series asked before. I had to run a search separately to find questions on the series (so as to figure out what tag they were using).

Comment: It's just not really user-friendly.

Comment: I meant that tag excerpts should solve the problem by including the most commonly used variants of a work's name, so that they will appear in tag list if you type one of them.

Comment: Hmmmm, weirdly enough, they didn't here. I did get the English title from the tag exerpt here, but the contents of the tag excerpt don't show up in the tag list unless the word I'm typing is already in the tag itself: for instance, I typed `flowers` in the tags page, and did not get [tag:aku-no-hana].

Comment: If you find a series missing English title, you can flag for synonym creation. Do use Google to look for the official/localized title, though.

Comment: See also: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/933/

Comment: @Hakase Tag searches on /tags and in the tag autocompleter box when asking a question both don't search tag excerpts. They only search tag names (including synonym names).

Comment: @Maroon Incidentally, I added a syn for [the-flowers-of-evil] to [aku-no-hana]

Answer (score 3):

The problem with [the-irregular-at-magic-high-school](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-irregular-at-magic-high-school) is that it's over 25 characters long, which is the maximum tag length. We do have synonyms between the English and Japanese versions of serieses.

If you can suggest a decent, intuitive English tag name, I'll happily add it as a synonym (Also, you can suggest it easily from the tag's page, under `synonyms`).

Comment: I can't suggest synonyms without a score of 5 from answers -- I only have a score of 2 (and pretty much only because I once saw a question I could answer without knowledge of the series). I was going to suggest something like [tag:irregular-magic-high-school], but that's apparently still 2 characters too long. I suppose omitting `high` would get the count sufficiently down, particularly since the main issue for me is that I'd want someone typing `the irregular` or `irregular` to be able to locate the tag.

Comment: Can we ask the dev to raise the character limit?

Comment: @nhahtdh Hahahaha I wish. There's [a feature request for this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209248/) on Meta.SE, but I doubt this is ever going to happen because of course SO doesn't need long tags, so why would anyone else?